# Contextual Substitution with LuaLateX

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec, accents, libertine

Contextual substition doesn't seem to work with LuaLateX, while it works fine with XeLateX. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
\textvbaraccent{i} fä f?
\end{document}
```

**XeLaTeX**

[image]

**LuaLaTeX**

[image]

(notice the spacing between the upper part of the 'f' and the first dot of the 'ä' and the space between the 'f' and the '?')

Comment: I can confirm. TeX Live 2012.

Comment: With MiKTeX 2.9, I get the same output as yours for LuaLaTeX; however my XeLaTeX output doesn't seem to do too well with the substitutions either: the [Tittle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tittle "i-dot") and the vertical bar accent are layered on top of each other, and the alternate f isn't used at all: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5ows.png

Comment: That's really weird, the space between the 'f' and the '?' is even smaller for you, to the point where they are touching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to have been solved with the new release of TeX Live 2013 (presently in test version). Here's the output obtained with

```
> lualatex --version
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013052718  (TeX Live 2013) (rev 4627)

Execute  'luatex --credits'  for credits and version details.

There is NO warranty. Redistribution of this software is covered by
the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2 or (at your option)
any later version. For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the LuaTeX source.

Copyright 2013 Taco Hoekwater, the LuaTeX Team.
```

[image]

And here's the file list

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
fontspec.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
   expl3.sty    2013/03/14 v4469 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper
 l3names.sty    2012/12/07 v4346 L3 Namespace for primitives
l3bootstrap.sty    2013/01/08 v4420 L3 Experimental bootstrap code
  luatex.sty    2010/03/09 v0.4 LuaTeX basic definition package (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
luatex-loader.sty    2010/03/09 v0.4 Lua module loader (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
l3basics.sty    2013/01/10 v4428 L3 Basic definitions
 l3expan.sty    2013/02/03 v4458 L3 Argument expansion
    l3tl.sty    2013/01/08 v4415 L3 Token lists
   l3seq.sty    2013/01/12 v4434 L3 Sequences and stacks
   l3int.sty    2013/01/13 v4444 L3 Integers
 l3quark.sty    2012/11/04 v4268 L3 Quarks
   l3prg.sty    2013/02/13 v4459 L3 Control structures
 l3clist.sty    2013/01/08 v4414 L3 Comma separated lists
 l3token.sty    2013/01/10 v4428 L3 Experimental token manipulation
  l3prop.sty    2013/01/09 v4423 L3 Property lists
   l3msg.sty    2013/01/08 v4412 L3 Messages
  l3file.sty    2013/01/14 v4446 L3 File and I/O operations
  l3skip.sty    2013/01/13 v4444 L3 Dimensions and skips
  l3keys.sty    2013/02/24 v4461 L3 Experimental key-value interfaces
    l3fp.sty    2013/01/19 v4449 L3 Floating points
   l3box.sty    2013/01/08 v4411 L3 Experimental boxes
l3coffins.sty    2012/09/09 v4212 L3 Coffin code layer
 l3color.sty    2012/08/29 v4156 L3 Experimental color support
l3luatex.sty    2012/08/03 v4049 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
l3candidates.sty    2013/03/14 v4468 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
  xparse.sty    2013/03/12 v4467 L3 Experimental document command parser
luaotfload.sty    2013/05/23 v2.2d OpenType layout system
luatexbase.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Resource management for the LuaTeX macro progr
ammer
luatexbase-compat.sty    2011/05/24 v0.4 Compatibility tools for LuaTeX
luatexbase-modutils.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Module utilities for LuaTeX
luatexbase-loader.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Lua module loader for LuaTeX
luatexbase-regs.sty    2011/05/24 v0.4 Registers allocation for LuaTeX
luatexbase-attr.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Attributes allocation for LuaTeX
luatexbase-cctb.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Catcodetable allocation for LuaTeX
luatexbase-mcb.sty    2013/05/11 v0.6 Callback management for LuaTeX
fontspec-patches.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

fixltx2e.sty    2006/09/13 v1.1m fixes to LaTeX
fontspec-luatex.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
  eu2enc.def    2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
  eu2lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
xunicode.sty    2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many othe
r characters in Unicode lower plane
 eu2lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
fontspec.cfg
   t3cmr.fd    2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```